# Getting an assoc or numeric array from a MySQLi prepared statement NOT WORKING

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I can't getting an assoc or numeric array from a mysqli prepared statement. I searched and researched from code to get it but it have been imposible. I generate this code based on all that codes. I really think that's correct but it doesn't work anyway:

```
    $id = '134610';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

            while ($array = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
                               // or fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
            print_r($array);
```

Comment: So, what is the output?

Comment: There's no output. The execution server execution stops. There's no error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve it with that code:

```
$id = '134610';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$array = self::bind_result_array($stmt);
for($i=0;$stmt->fetch();$i++)
    $ArrayOfArrays[$i] = self::getCopy($array);
$stmt->close();
return $ArrayOfArrays;
```

and this two functions:

```
public function bind_result_array($stmt)
{
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
$result = array();
while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
{
    $result[$field->name] = NULL;
    $params[] = &$result[$field->name];
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
return $result;
}


public function getCopy($row)
{
return array_map(create_function('$a', 'return $a;'), $row);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> MYSQLI_ASSOC
>     Columns are returned into the array having the fieldname as the array index.
>
> MYSQLI_NUM
>     Columns are returned into the array having an enumerated index.
> ```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, but it doesn't work in any of those ways. I have been testing both of them. I'll edit my question correcting the error. Thanks!